# Mimekit: parse filtered Mbox results to new Mbox

Tags: c#, mimekit

After parsing an Mbox, filtering message(s) by a condition, and writing those messages into a new stream => file, the resulting Mbox is missing the FROM lines.  Can you tell me if I'm making a code mistake or if there is a bug in the MimeParser function?

example code:

```
    using System.IO;
    using MimeKit;

    namespace mboxScan
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                // Grab local .mbox file
                var stream = MboxStream(@"C:\temp\user.mbox");

                // Filter logic
                string fromFilter = "it@abc.com";

                // Load every message from a Unix mbox
                var parser = new MimeParser(stream, MimeFormat.Mbox);

                // Create new stream for results
                var exportStream = new MemoryStream();

                while (!parser.IsEndOfStream)
                {
                    var message = parser.ParseMessage();
                    if (message.From.ToString().Contains(fromFilter))
                    {
                        // Write this message to exportStream 
                        message.WriteTo(exportStream);      
                    }                                                
                }

                // ** Save exportStream to new MBOX
                exportStream.Position = 0;
                using (var fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\temp\results.mbox"))
                {
                    exportStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    exportStream.CopyTo(fileStream);
                }
            }

            static Stream MboxStream(string s)
            {
                Stream fs = File.OpenRead(s);
                return fs;
            }
        }
    }
```

and the results start with:

Delivered-To:

Comment: To clarify, I'm missing the very first line of the message, as seen in the original Mbox, (e.g.): From 1471095924502510663-32fef6b9-dbc2-4527-a3e8-28dd901c299b.mbox@xxx Mon Jun 16 07:20:00 2014

Comment: I found the line: `var topLine = parser.MboxMarker;`

Answer (score 2):

Sorry folks - you're watching me learn in real-time ;-)
parser.MboxMarker is that first "From " line and it's rightfully not part of the message object properties because it's an aspect of Mbox format, not the message.  So with that in mind - you can capture that line and insert it into memory before the message.WriteTo() function as such:

```
var topLine = parser.MboxMarker;
MemoryStream mStream =
   new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(topLine));
            mStream.WriteTo(exportStream);
            mStream.Dispose();
```